# Can my familiar use a Ring of Spell Storing?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, familiars, concentration

Can the familiar options from the Pact of the Chain warlock (quasit, imp, sprite, pseudodragon) attune with a *ring of spell storing*?

If so, can I cast a spell requiring concentration into the ring and then have the familiar maintain concentration on the spell?

Comment: Related, possible (partial) duplicate: [Can a familiar use a magic item to cast a concentration spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/159527/can-a-familiar-use-a-magic-item-to-cast-a-concentration-spell) Also related: [Can a familiar attune and wear or use a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107328/can-a-familiar-attune-and-wear-or-use-a-magic-item), [Can an animal attune to a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115569/can-an-animal-attune-to-a-magic-item)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The section on attunement is quite long, so I won't reproduce it here, but it refers exclusively to a "creature". It doesn't say anything about a player, a player character, a humanoid, or anything else that would exclude familiars from being able to attune to magic items.

The *ring of spell storing* itself likewise has no restriction beyond requiring attunement, so yes, a familiar can attune to it. I feel compelled to point out that some DMs might not allow a pseudodragon to use a ring because it doesn't have fingers, though.

As for concentration, the DMG says this about items that cast spells (on page 141):

> The spell uses its normal casting time, range, and duration, and the user of the item must concentrate if the spell requires concentration.

So if you cast a spell into the ring that requires concentration, when your familiar uses the ring to cast it, your familiar will have to maintain concentration, not you.

Comment: Toe-on-a-forelimb might be close enough to a finger for some DMs (I'd be inclined to allow it)

Comment: @Adeptus So would I! I just figured I'd better have the disclaimer just in case. Hence "**some** DMs" and "**might** not allow".