# Can a familiar's greater steed(s) 'Reincarnate' with a Ring of Spell Storing?

Tags: dnd-5e

**Can a flock of Pegasii summoned mounts *Reincarnate* any humanoid with a (properly loaded) *Ring of Spell Storing*?**

The points below are not really new per se but rather a cumulative-inductive discovery of StackExchange rulings. This is listed below:

- A familiar &/or summoned mount can [cast any spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70692/can-my-familiar-use-a-ring-of-spell-storing) from a Ring of Spell Storing.
- A [Ring of Spell Storing](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ring%20of%20Spell%20Storing#content) stores up to five spell-levels - thus fifth lvl max. (hence this includes *Reincarnation*)
- The casting / catching of spells (specifically *'Reincarnate'* in this case) [does not seem to require components](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76556/how-does-a-ring-of-spell-storing-function). Thus the 1000 gold worth of rare [unguents](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unguent) is neither needed to 'charge' the ring, nor cast-use it.
- Correct use of various *summoning* spells + *Ring o' SpellStore®* allows each familiar &/or steed to have one (1) familiar + one (1) steed each, hence: [Menagerie Ad nauseum](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/148416/can-a-ring-of-spell-storing-and-access-to-find-spells-produce-an-endless-menager).

Thus it seems that any character *with previous access-planning to the right summoning and necromatic spells* could have a flight of a few thousand loyal [Pegasii](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Pegasus#content) striving to [Reincarnate](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Reincarnate#content) them (should they die).

If so: this seems impressive &/or surprising.

Comment: There is no "I" in "Pegasus."  Therefore, there cannot be more than one "I" in the plural, which is "Pegasi."

Comment: I really dislike the 'can I abuse the mechanics in this way' questions. No DM will let you do this.

Comment: @SeriousBri Some GMs totally will. I had a Star Wars Saga GM let me do something similar with Tech Specialist and building an emergency back-up fleet of droid fighters, because half the party decided that PVP was all fun and games. In my defence, they started it :P

Comment: @SeriousBri It depends on what kind of story you are telling. In my experience, this kind of activity does not mesh well with the typical stories that D&D is used to tell, but everyone plays D&D differently.

Answer (score 6):

### Storing a spell in the ring requires components as normal.

> Any creature can cast a spell of 1st through 5th level into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast. The spell has no effect, other than to be stored in the ring. If the ring can't hold the spell, the spell is expended without effect. The level of the slot used to cast the spell determines how much space it uses.

There's nothing there about not requiring components. The only way it changes the process of casting a spell is that the spell doesn't take effect.

I suspect you're misreading [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/76572/48793), which explains that casting a spell *from* the ring doesn't require components.

Comment: Could you address the answer to the [referenced Q/A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/76572/48793) which states that the ring bypasses the need for components?

Comment: So *loading* the ring requires the components. This is very good to know and thank you. But is that it? The rest holds water?

Comment: @Rykara i noticed that casting from the ring required no components and i did not see mention of them in the loading. I was confused and needed correction, hence the value of StackExchange. My apologies / learned plenty.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that *reincarnation* still has a casting time of 1 hour (even when cast through the ring), so it's not like the pegasus could regularly *reincarnate* the character in combat.